# AJAX JQUERY codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

hy , I use AJAx in my project

```
<?php foreach ($dt_pesanan_detail->result_array() as $key) {    ?>
<tr class="content">
<td class="td-keranjang" id="id_kelas"><?php echo $key['nama_menu']; ?></td>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#id_kelas").change(function(){
            var id_kelas = {id_kelas:$("#id_kelas").val()};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax",
                    data: id_kelas,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#siswa').html(msg);
                    }
                });
    });


        </script>
```

but this code only for array index 1 , if result $dt_pesanan_detail more then 2 row,why j query only run in 1 row, 2 row can't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you're generating that script in every iteration of the array `$dt_pesanan_detail`. The 2nd (and real issue) is that ID's are unique, and therefore you can't do what you're trying to achieve. Therefore, perform these adjustments:

```
<?php foreach ($dt_pesanan_detail->result_array() as #key) {    ?>
<tr class="content">
    <td class="td-keranjang" id="id_kelas" class="id_kelas">
```

Then don't generate the script in your `foreach loop`.

```
$(".id_kelas").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax",
        data: id_kelas,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#siswa').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```